# Can we share GooglePlus_ClientID and GoogkePlus_simpleAPI_key?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I want to use googleplus API for my Android application.

Can I share my googeplus Client ID and API keys in menifest.xml file without any security being compromised?

Can somebody do some malicious activity using this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could exhaust your API call quota by impersonating your app. Then your app will stop working (either temporarily or permanently if they ban your key). That said, for your app to work, they need to be inside the app, so you have to put them there. You might try to obfuscate them somewhat to make them less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to setup client authentication in Android than using the simple API key.  Full instructions are available from the [Google+ Platform for Android page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started). At a high level, the following steps are taken:

1. Create a client ID for Android using your package name and a signing fingerprint from your Android keystore. This will protect your application because only you can sign your apps.
2. Use the [Google Play Services SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/package-summary.html) to perform operations against the Google+ API.

You will not need to authenticate in the same sense that you would for Web applications because your package and its certificate are sufficient to identify your application. For this reason, you will need a unique package per application.

Comment: This is certainly easier to use, but is not exactly more secure. While you can take steps to protect the API key, the info Google Play Services uses -- your package name and the *fingerprint* (SHA1 hash) of your signing certificate, are actually public information. So anyone  can impersonate your app, without even decompiling it. Additionally, Google Play Services does not offer a full G+ API yet (although it's basically there, just not exposed).

Comment: Some more info on the subject here (in the 'Google Play Services' section): http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-online-account-management.html